# Possible to change an apps SSAID aka Android_ID without rebooting? Which service handles this? Fast rebooting with Zygote kills my shell script

Tags: adb, shell, development

This may seem like an odd question, and I apologize for that. I am currently debugging an application and I am having trouble getting new Android_ID's to stick without rebooting.

To be specific these are the new app specific android ID's introduced in 8.0. The location for these ID's are in the following file: `/data/system/users/0/settings_ssaid.xml`

I am able to change the app specific ID just fine but it doesn't actually change unless I reboot the device.

Is there a certain service or process that I can force-restart to make the new ID to take effect? Or possibly some type of cache that needs cleared?

I am mainly using adb shell commands. So far the best method is to run the following command:

`adb shell setprop ctl.restart zygote`

This does a 'soft' reboot, so it's much faster but unfortunately it completely kills my shell script that is debugging as well and it's a pain to keep restarting everything.

Is there a way to see what services or processes are being restarted when restarting 'zygote'?

Much appreciate the help in advance.

Comment: Almost everything related to apps settings is cached in `system_server` which is the Android framework and a core component of Zygote. So the only way to clear cache is to kill the process. There are hundreds of services running inside `system_server` and many of those are accessible through commandline tools. But I have never come across a method to clear cache. Some time ago I was looking for a way to clear SQLite cache. // Keeping shell script running when Zygote is killed is possible with root access.

Comment: I do have root access, how would it be possible to keep the script running? Just run as super user? Thanks for the reply.